# Qt phonon play video automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, phonon

I’m currently working to develop simple application for information kiosk under Windows 7 platform.

This is my 2nd project using Python3.4 + qt designer + pyqt to build the interface and code.

In this project i want to use phonon video player(K-lite codec installed) to play all video and it should be a cross-platform application(will deploy into RPI 3).

Up to now, i have a few roadblocks and still can’t configure how to solve it even-though googling everywhere. Below are some of the problems that i’m looking for solution;

- Main window contain a tabwidget, Home, Menu and Preferences. Under Home tab, i did insert Phonon video player to play an intro video automatically when detect action. The video should keep looping if no mouse movement detected. If there is mouse movement detected, it should shift to Menu tab for further action. How can i do that in smart way?[image: MainWindow TabWidget]
- Under Menu tab, there are push button created to allow display the information video. Right now, i managed to play the video when user clicked in fullscreen mode but didn’t know how to exit the fullscreen and stop the backend player if user want to quit. [image: tab_Menu]

Below is the code for reference;

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):       
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_mainWindow.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.media = Phonon.MediaObject(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.toolButton_A.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.toolButton_B.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.toolButton_C.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        #self.uploadButton_A.clicked.connect(self.file_save)
        self.pushButton_corp.clicked.connect(self.playVideo_corp)
        self.pushButton_product.clicked.connect (self.playVideo_product)
        self.pushButton_fab.clicked.connect(self.playVideo_fab)
        self.pushButton_Start.clicked.connect(self.playVideo_intro)
        self.window2 = None


    def on_click(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open File","",'All Files (*)')
        if filename:
            print(filename)
            buttonreply = QMessageBox.question(self,'Message Box', 'Are you confirm?',QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
            if buttonreply == QMessageBox.Yes:
                print ('Yes clicked.')
            else:
                print ('No clicked.')


    def videoPlayer_home1(self):

        vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
        media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\Users\\mohd_faizal4\\Desktop\\RPI Kiosk\\start-logo-new2-12s.mp4')
        vp.load(media)
        vp.play()
        vp.show()

    def playVideo_intro(self):

        vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
        vp.showFullScreen()
        media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\Users\\mohd_faizal4\\Desktop\\RPI Kiosk\\start-logo-new2-12s.mp4')
        vp.load(media)
        vp.play()
        vp.show()
        #size = self.vp.size()
        #self.vp.resize(size)
        sys.stdout()

    def playVideo_fab(self):

        vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
        vp.showFullScreen()
        media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\Users\\mohd_faizal4\\Desktop\\RPI Kiosk\\MyFabFaces-5.mp4')
        vp.load(media)
        vp.play()
        vp.show()
        sys.stdout()

    def playVideo_corp(self):
        vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
        vp.showFullScreen()
        media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\Users\\mohd_faizal4\\Desktop\\RPI Kiosk\\Intro-2017-01.mp4')
        vp.load(media)
        vp.play()
        vp.show()
        sys.stdout()

    def playVideo_product(self):

        vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
        vp.showFullScreen()
        media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\Users\\mohd_faizal4\\Desktop\\RPI Kiosk\\End-Applications-2017-01.mp4')
        vp.load(media)
        vp.play()
        vp.show()
        sys.stdout()

    # Switch to Menu tab once detect mouse event
    def menu_tab(self):
        print('tab changed to Menu!')
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.tab_menu)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   Window = MainWindow()
   Window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
   sys.stdout()
```

Below is the code for Ui_mainwindow;

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
   def _fromUtf8(s):
    return s

try:
_encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
   def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
   def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
    mainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainWindow"))
    mainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
    mainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(mainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    mainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/image/silterra.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    mainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
    mainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(mainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
    self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
    self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(229, 243, 
255);\n"
""))
    self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtGui.QTabWidget.North)
    self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Triangular)
    self.tabWidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(18, 18))
    self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideMiddle)
    self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
    self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(False)
    self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
    self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
    self.tab_home = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab_home.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_home"))
    self.videoPlayer_home = phonon.Phonon.VideoPlayer(self.tab_home)
    self.videoPlayer_home.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1921, 841))
    self.videoPlayer_home.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("videoPlayer_home"))
    self.pushButton_Start = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_home)
    self.pushButton_Start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(840, 700, 91, 41))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_Start.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_Start.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"))
    self.pushButton_Start.setFlat(False)
    self.pushButton_Start.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_Start"))
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_home, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.tab_menu = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab_menu.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_menu"))
    self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab_menu)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080))
    self.label_6.setLineWidth(2)
    self.label_6.setMidLineWidth(0)
    self.label_6.setText(_fromUtf8(""))

self.label_6.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/image/photonics1.jpg")))
    self.label_6.setScaledContents(True)
    self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
    self.pushButton_corp = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_menu)
    self.pushButton_corp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 260, 441, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("MS Shell Dlg 2"))
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    font.setKerning(True)
    self.pushButton_corp.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_corp.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.pushButton_corp.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);"))
    self.pushButton_corp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_corp"))
    self.pushButton_product = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_menu)
    self.pushButton_product.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 380, 441, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("MS Shell Dlg 2"))
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    font.setKerning(True)
    self.pushButton_product.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_product.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.pushButton_product.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);"))
    self.pushButton_product.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_product"))
    self.pushButton_fab = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_menu)
    self.pushButton_fab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 500, 441, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("MS Shell Dlg 2"))
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    font.setKerning(True)
    self.pushButton_fab.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_fab.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.pushButton_fab.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);"))
    self.pushButton_fab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_fab"))
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_menu, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.tab_preferences = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab_preferences.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_preferences"))
    self.frame_4 = QtGui.QFrame(self.tab_preferences)
    self.frame_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 661, 231))
    self.frame_4.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:0, stop:0 rgba(21, 79, 84, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(238, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));"))
    self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.Box)
    self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.frame_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_4"))
    self.toolButton_A = QtGui.QToolButton(self.frame_4)
    self.toolButton_A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 40, 41, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setItalic(False)
    font.setUnderline(False)
    font.setStrikeOut(False)
    self.toolButton_A.setFont(font)
    self.toolButton_A.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.toolButton_A.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.toolButton_A.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: 
qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 243, 
240, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
 "border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"))
    self.toolButton_A.setCheckable(False)
    self.toolButton_A.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
    self.toolButton_A.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
    self.toolButton_A.setAutoRaise(True)
    self.toolButton_A.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.NoArrow)
    self.toolButton_A.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolButton_A"))
    self.textBrowser_A = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.frame_4)
    self.textBrowser_A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 401, 31))
    self.textBrowser_A.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(252, 255, 247, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));"))
    self.textBrowser_A.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_A"))
    self.label_videoA = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_4)
    self.label_videoA.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 71, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_videoA.setFont(font)
    self.label_videoA.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.label_videoA.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);"))
    self.label_videoA.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.label_videoA.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label_videoA.setWordWrap(False)
    self.label_videoA.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_videoA"))
    self.uploadButton_A = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_4)
    self.uploadButton_A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 40, 71, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.uploadButton_A.setFont(font)
    self.uploadButton_A.setAutoDefault(False)
    self.uploadButton_A.setDefault(False)
    self.uploadButton_A.setFlat(False)
    self.uploadButton_A.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("uploadButton_A"))
    self.label_videoB = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_4)
    self.label_videoB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 71, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_videoB.setFont(font)
    self.label_videoB.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.label_videoB.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);"))
    self.label_videoB.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.label_videoB.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label_videoB.setWordWrap(False)
    self.label_videoB.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_videoB"))
    self.textBrowser_B = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.frame_4)
    self.textBrowser_B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 90, 401, 31))
    self.textBrowser_B.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(252, 255, 247, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));"))
    self.textBrowser_B.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_B"))
    self.label_videoC = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_4)
    self.label_videoC.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 71, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_videoC.setFont(font)
    self.label_videoC.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.label_videoC.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);"))
    self.label_videoC.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.label_videoC.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label_videoC.setWordWrap(False)
    self.label_videoC.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_videoC"))
    self.textBrowser_C = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.frame_4)
    self.textBrowser_C.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 140, 401, 31))
    self.textBrowser_C.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(252, 255, 247, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));"))
    self.textBrowser_C.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_C"))
    self.toolButton_B = QtGui.QToolButton(self.frame_4)
    self.toolButton_B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 90, 41, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setItalic(False)
    font.setUnderline(False)
    font.setStrikeOut(False)
    self.toolButton_B.setFont(font)
    self.toolButton_B.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.toolButton_B.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.toolButton_B.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 243, 240, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"))
    self.toolButton_B.setCheckable(False)
    self.toolButton_B.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
    self.toolButton_B.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
    self.toolButton_B.setAutoRaise(True)
    self.toolButton_B.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.NoArrow)
    self.toolButton_B.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolButton_B"))
    self.toolButton_C = QtGui.QToolButton(self.frame_4)
    self.toolButton_C.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 140, 41, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setItalic(False)
    font.setUnderline(False)
    font.setStrikeOut(False)
    self.toolButton_C.setFont(font)
    self.toolButton_C.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.toolButton_C.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.toolButton_C.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 243, 240, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"))
    self.toolButton_C.setCheckable(False)
    self.toolButton_C.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
    self.toolButton_C.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
    self.toolButton_C.setAutoRaise(True)
    self.toolButton_C.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.NoArrow)
    self.toolButton_C.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolButton_C"))
    self.uploadButton_B = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_4)
    self.uploadButton_B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 90, 71, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.uploadButton_B.setFont(font)
    self.uploadButton_B.setAutoDefault(False)
    self.uploadButton_B.setDefault(False)
    self.uploadButton_B.setFlat(False)
    self.uploadButton_B.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("uploadButton_B"))
    self.uploadButton_C = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_4)
    self.uploadButton_C.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 140, 71, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.uploadButton_C.setFont(font)
    self.uploadButton_C.setAutoDefault(False)
    self.uploadButton_C.setDefault(False)
    self.uploadButton_C.setFlat(False)
    self.uploadButton_C.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("uploadButton_C"))
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_preferences, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.actionNew = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    self.actionNew.setCheckable(False)
    icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../.designer/backup/Icon/new.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.actionNew.setIcon(icon1)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    self.actionNew.setFont(font)
    self.actionNew.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionNew"))
    self.actionOpen = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../.designer/backup/Icon/open.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.actionOpen.setIcon(icon2)
    self.actionOpen.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionOpen"))
    self.actionRecent_Result = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    self.actionRecent_Result.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionRecent_Result"))
    self.actionSave = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../.designer/backup/Icon/save.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.actionSave.setIcon(icon3)
    self.actionSave.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionSave"))
    self.actionSave_As = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../.designer/backup/Icon/save as.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.actionSave_As.setIcon(icon4)
    self.actionSave_As.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionSave_As"))
    self.actionPrint = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../.designer/backup/Icon/print.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.actionPrint.setIcon(icon5)
    self.actionPrint.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionPrint"))
    self.actionClose = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    self.actionClose.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionClose"))
    self.actionExit = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    self.actionExit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionExit"))
    self.actionAbout_i_MIS = QtGui.QAction(mainWindow)
    self.actionAbout_i_MIS.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionAbout_i_MIS"))

    self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionExit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("triggered()")), mainWindow.close)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Silterra Information Kiosk", None))
    self.pushButton_Start.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Start", None))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_home), _translate("mainWindow", "Home", None))
    self.pushButton_corp.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Corporate Intro and Info", None))
    self.pushButton_product.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "End-Application Products", None))
    self.pushButton_fab.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Virtual Fab (Cleanroom) Tour", None))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_menu), _translate("mainWindow", "Menu", None))
    self.toolButton_A.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "...", None))
    self.label_videoA.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Video A", None))
    self.uploadButton_A.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Upload", None))
    self.label_videoB.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Video B", None))
    self.label_videoC.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Video C", None))
    self.toolButton_B.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "...", None))
    self.toolButton_C.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "...", None))
    self.uploadButton_B.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Upload", None))
    self.uploadButton_C.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Upload", None))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_preferences), _translate("mainWindow", "Preferences", None))
    self.actionNew.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "New", None))
    self.actionNew.setShortcut(_translate("mainWindow", "Ctrl+N", None))
    self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Open", None))
    self.actionOpen.setShortcut(_translate("mainWindow", "Ctrl+O", None))
    self.actionRecent_Result.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Recent Result", None))
    self.actionSave.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Save", None))
    self.actionSave.setShortcut(_translate("mainWindow", "Ctrl+S", None))
    self.actionSave_As.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Save As", None))
    self.actionSave_As.setShortcut(_translate("mainWindow", "Ctrl+Shift+S", None))
    self.actionPrint.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Print", None))
    self.actionPrint.setShortcut(_translate("mainWindow", "Ctrl+P", None))
    self.actionClose.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Close", None))
    self.actionClose.setShortcut(_translate("mainWindow", "Ctrl+C", None))
    self.actionExit.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Exit", None))
    self.actionExit.setShortcut(_translate("mainWindow", "Ctrl+E", None))
    self.actionAbout_i_MIS.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "About i-MIS", None))

from PyQt4 import phonon
import images_rc
import resources_rc
```

Comment: 1. Should I move the mouse, should I change to the Menu? 2.What action should the user do so that they know they want to leave the app?

Comment: 1. Yes, it should change to the Menu when move the mouse. 2. The user may use the keyboard shortcut key(q) if they want to quit the video.

Comment: You could share the design code.

Comment: @eyllanesc code attached at the end of question.

Comment: I mean the Ui_mainWindow class, share that code to be able to test your code.

Comment: Ui_mainWindow code updated.

Comment: Will anyone help me on the possible solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164915/discussion-between-faizal-a-and-eyllanesc).